# Conditional formatting dates with if statement

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a list of customers I want to regularly visit. Some customers I want to visit more often than others. Customers have been rated +,++ and - depending on how often I want to go.

I want to visit customers rated + every 90 days, ++ every 60 days and customers rated - every 120 days.
I want to make it so that row A which contains dates has formatting rules corresponding to every rating, so if I want to change a customers rating the rule corresponding to that rating will apply. For example, if a customer is rated + and I change the rating to ++ the rule for ++ applies instead of +.

How do I combine an IF statement with a conditional formatting rule, so if a cell in column B is ++, the corresponding cell in column A turns red after 60 days?

I have listed the day I last visited each customer next to their name and applied the rule "=A3<Today()-90" in conditional formatting to row A. So now the cells in row A turn red 90 days after my last visit.

[image]

I have trouble combining the Today rule with an IF statement. I have tried to combine "=IF(B3=++;A3<Today()-60" but I get error messages saying the formula lacks a parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a helper column "next visit".
And to have more flexibilty add a configuration table for the visiting deltas.

[image]

Formula for "next visit":

`=[@[Last Visit]]+INDEX(tblSettings[Frequency],MATCH([@Rating],tblSettings[Rating],0))`

Formula for the format condition:

`=$B4<=TODAY()`